# Is there a way to store images in google cloud sql?

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

My android app uses Google cloud endpoints as back-end server and Google cloud SQL as the database. There is a new requirement now to store images. My research till now tells me that Google cloud storage is the way to go if I need to store images.Before I plan to migrate to cloud storage, I would like to give a try here to see if anyone is aware of storing images in cloud SQL too .

If anyone has any information on storing an image(for profile picture) in Cloud SQL , let me know the way to do it. Also I am using java in the back end.

Comment: it's just mysql, so presumably it's just mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html

Comment: In your database store the url for the image and then the client can download/cache the image from cloud storage. If you put loads of images in cloud sql it will get expensive I would imagine!

Answer (score 3):

The sample application contains an android application that allows a user to take and upload photographs to Google App Engine Service.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-orchestrator-android-sampleapp-smashpix

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.Since i am not familiar with python,I might take time to grasp it though. It would be great if you are aware of any java project/snippets too.